# Integrate cloud run with exiting service mesh

Tags: google-cloud-run

We have an existing service mesh built using Envoy and internal service control and discovery stack. We want to offer cloud run to our developers. How can we integrate the cloud run into the mesh network so that:
1, The cloud run containers can talk to the mesh services.
2, The services built using cloud run can be discovered and used by other mesh services (each has a Envoy sidecar)

Comment: I'm not sure that you will be able to use the Cloud Run add on on GKE. However, you can have a look to its open source equivalent: knative. I know that knative can work with several mesh, and not only Istio. For your developer, they will need to use the CLI to deploy and not the Cloud Run console, it's the only one difference.

Answer (score 0):

The GCP docs cover this with the [Cloud Run for Anthos services using Istio](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authorizing-access-to-cloud-run-on-gke-services-using-istio) doc.

In a nutshell, you will need to:

- Create a GKE cluster with Cloud Run enabled.
- Deploy a sample service to Cloud Run for Anthos on Google Cloud.
- Create an IAM service account.
- Create an Istio authentication policy.
- Create an Istio authorization policy.
- Test the solution.

But things change depending on how your existing service mesh is configured. Elaborating on that portion can allow the community to be able to better assist you.